# matlab-like element-wise operations (broadcasting) on non-conformable arrays in r

Tags: r, arrays, matlab

What's the most straightforward way to replicate the following MATLAB behavior in R?

```
reshape(1:6, [3, 1, 2]) - reshape(6:-1:1, [1, 3, 2])

ans(:,:,1) =

    -5    -4    -3
    -4    -3    -2
    -3    -2    -1


ans(:,:,2) =

     1     2     3
     2     3     4
     3     4     5
```

Obviously non-conformable in R:

```
array(1:6, dim = c(3, 1, 2)) - array(6:1, dim = c(1, 3, 2))
Error in array(1:6, dim = c(3, 1, 2)) - array(6:1, dim = c(1, 3, 2)) : 
  non-conformable arrays
```

Comment: I don't know R, but in case it helps with searching, this behaviour is usually called "broadcasting" (although in Matlab it has a different name)

Comment: @LuisMendo, thank you. Your tip led me to the `rray` package. `rray(1:6, c(3, 1, 2)) - rray(6:1, c(1, 3, 2))` works as desired.

Comment: Great! This can be a good question for R users not very experienced with the language or with the package; if you have time maybe add an expanded version of your comment as an answer